# Decomposition of a specific $SO(n)$-representation into irreducible ones

Tags: representation-theory

I need to decompose a specific $SO(n)$-representation into irreducible ones, but my background on representation theory is rather weak, so I post the problem here.

Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional real vector space. Consider the space $S^2V^*\otimes V$ of symmetric bilinear maps $f: V\times V\rightarrow V$. Let $E\subset S^2V^*\otimes V$ be the subspace consisting of bilinear maps $f$ satisfying the condition that $f(v,\cdot)\in\mathrm{End}(V)$ is traceless for any $v\in V$.

Now, we view $V$ as a $SO(n)$-module by prescribing a scalar product on $V$. Then $E$ is also a $SO(n)$-module.

> **Question:** How does $E$ decomposes into irreducible $SO(n)$-submodules (at least when $n$ is odd)?

Comment: I guess one needs to be really careful with the description of the module structure. Of course there is a natural $SO(n)$-module structure on $V$. There is also one on $V^* \cong V$ ($w\in V$ corresponds to $\langle w,-\rangle$) by precomposing with the inverse, i.e. $f\in SO(n), \ell \in V^*$ then $f\cdot \ell = \ell \circ f^{-1}$. Then there is a natural module structure on $S^2V^*\otimes V$ by the diagonal action. But if you take precomposing (with the inverse) as the $SO(n)$-module structure on $\operatorname{End}(V)$, then this corresponds to $V^*\otimes V$ with the trivial action on $V$.

Comment: Now you want to have a map $\tr_v \colon S^2 V^* \otimes V \to \End(V)$ and $E$ is supposed to be the intersection of all kernels for $v\in V$. But with the described module structures $\tr_v$ is not a module homomorphism. So can you be more carefully describe the module structures you are looking at?

Comment: @PeterPatzt I always assume that $GL(V)$ acts diagonally on tensor products of copies of $V$ and $V^*$. In particular, for $V^*\otimes V=End(V)$, this is the conjugation action. Then $S^2V^*\otimes V$ is a $GL(V)$-invariant subspace of $V^*\otimes V^*\otimes V$, while $E$ is the intersection of $S^2V^*\otimes V$ with the kernel of the $GL(V)$-equivariant map $Tr_{23}:V^*\otimes V^*\otimes V\rightarrow V^*$ (taking trace of the second and third component).